# How show plain picture or plain text when no data available in TableView in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view used for showing my favourite video list. if no data available in the table view it will show this.
[image]

Comment: Take a new cell with identifier and design it as above. When you get array empty then return 1 in numberofrowsinsection and load this cell

Comment: Make a view like above and put condition in `tableView numberOfRowsInSection` to hide and show that view.`if(arr_data.count == 0) { no_data_view.hidden=NO; tbl_view.hidden=YES; } else { no_data_view.hidden=YES; tbl_view.hidden=NO }`

Comment: @BhavinRamani If His cell height is like 30 but as per above design It is like greater than 30 So he has to configure heightforrowatindexpath method too. So its better to take a new cell with custom height and load it

Comment: @Jecky But I have not tell him to configure cell or make cell design like this in `UITableviewCell`

Comment: U talk about view like If he creates view of 100 as per above design but He want cell of height 30 then he has to configure heightforrowatindexpath method for just that view @BhavinRamani

Comment: @Jecky I am not telling him to create that view inside `UITableViewCell`

Comment: OK, bhai I got It, U r just talking about second option in below answer

Comment: you can take view outside of tableview to display alert

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it inside the tableView specifically then you will have to create a cell for the tableView with same structure and handle the cell used made based on wether or not data is present. If no data is present, you will have to instantiate a different cell and when data is present, a different one.

Here is how i would do it instead:
You can initially set the tableView to hidden. And create a view with the required imageViews and labels and also set it to be hidden. Make this view outside and not as the cell. On fetching data, depending on the response, you can unhide one of the views.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (arr.count==0) {
         return 1;
    }
    return arr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *emptyMessageCellIdenifier = @"emptyMessageCell";
    NSString *datacellIdentifier = @"datacell";

    UITableViewCell *emptyMessageCell ;
    UITableViewCell *datacell ;


    if (arr.count == 0) {
        return emptycell;
    }
    else{
        return datacell;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.It's so easy. I take a uiview. and when list is empty, hide table view and show that uiview. It's really easy.